# Rmarkdown hist()

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to knit my rmd file to html in Rstudio, but when it get to hist() it exit with an error: " ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> hist". Any help help highly appreciated.

The code is similar to this:

````
```{r}
hist(diamonds$carat)
```
````

My session info:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18), 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggthemes_3.0.2 ggplot2_2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

RStudio (quite correctly) knits the documents in a clean session. Hence, which packages you’ve loaded in your current session is irrelevant.

Now, `diamonds` is an example dataset that comes with `ggplot2`. If you want to use it, you need to load `ggplot2` (or at least the dataset) inside your RMarkdown document:

````
```{r}
data(diamonds, package = 'ggplot2')
```
````

Comment: @HongOoi I address this in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you! It helps!